# task (operation) manager plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Whenever I see some blocked operation being executed on eclipse, I try to terminate it, but never succeeded. I'm thinking of any available task-manager plugin so that I can perform termination effectively.

Just similar to the task-managers on Windows OS, Google Chrome browser, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one. Its not possible to create one. The major reason is that the Jobs API doesn't mandate a job to respond the cancel() method. The job can continue to ignore the request and keep doing.